# How to assign variable to a name, and also store name at same time in python

Tags: python, variables

If I have a variable, say:

```
variable_name = 1
```

I am not able to easily regain the name I gave to the variable, in this case: "variable_name"
Therefore I was wondering if there is a method `assign_variable` to assign a variable but at the same time to record the name used to a list or a dictionary etc. ?

```
variable_name_list =[]
variable_name_list.append(assign_variable(variable_name = 1))

print(variable_name_list)
```

> ["variable_name"]

```
variable_name + 2
```

> 3

EDIT: All variables get recorded in a namespace, but the issue is that I want to call a function from another .py file and this function should then get the variable names from the variable in the current file.

Comment: It already gets recorded, in your namespace.  Look at `locals()`.

Comment: *if there is a method to assign a variable but at the same time to record the name used to [...] a dictionary* - yes. was there any problem when you tried to use a dictionary?

Comment: How about `my_dict = {'variable_name': 1}`?

Comment: @hmm, right, I could just use a dictionary.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Or just read the code you wrote?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille What do you mean?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I suspect the question relates to using Python in an interactive session, rather than writing code in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary, you can use:

```
dict = {"variable name": variable value}
print(dict["variable name"])
```

prints out variable value